# How can I design a structure for both static and dynamic data?

Tags: typescript, caching, data-structures, storage, system-design

Let me try to explain like this,
First part:
I'm developing an API for a moba game. This API receives data shared by the game publisher itself.
The data contains information such as user account information, detailed information about the match nd static game data about the game itself(maps,champions,items ...)
I will present some of this data to the user in the UI I designed. And with some of it, I'll feed an AI model and analyze its in-game performance.
The problem here is that I want to develop a cache system
So that the API doesn't constantly throw requests or fetch static data all the time
To do that ...

```
class API {
cache :ICache;
ctor(_cache : ICache){
this.cache = _cache
}


getSomeUserInfo(){
const data : User = fetch('europe.api.infos.com/user/matchinfos').then(res=>res.json()); // Consider this gets user data in json format and returns a js object

this.cache.add('user',data); // What I tried was to save the user data in the cache by entering a tag. 

}




interface ICache {
add : (tag : string , value : any)=> void,,


//some methods
}

class MongoCache implements ICache{
add(tag : string , value : any){// some code}

ctor(connectstr : string){//some code}
}
```

Then I asked myself the question, what about static data,
There is a huge amount of immutable data about the game. I wanted to design a system where I could control both dynamic user data and immutable big game data. I'm new to both software and this site. I hope I was able to explain myself. I would appreciate it if you could suggest at least theoretical resources, even if it is not a software recommendation.

Comment: What specific problem are you facing?

Comment: Hi @Teo98! Right now your question is pretty unclear. You ask "How can I do this?" but "a common data management class for data that changes in a short time and is static" is very vague. What _exactly_ is your goal? (maybe show some code deomnstrating that goal) What part of that are you have trouble with? How does the code you provided fail to meet that goal? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your question with a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and you will get much more help.